# Need Date Formula Assistance

Tags: excel, date

I need some formula help. I have a spreadsheet with an actual FINAL REPORT deadline date (ex. 09/14/2014), another column with wording "Due 2 Weeks Prior" and "Due 1 Week Prior". I need an additional column to calculate the actual date that the "2 weeks prior" or "1 week prior" would be. For example final deadline date is 09/14/2014, Detailed Due Date lists "Due 2 weeks Prior", I need a formula of how I could list 2 weeks prior to 09/14/2014, providing 09/01/2014 as the result. Help!

Answer (score 0):

With **9/14/2014** in cell **A1,** in another cell enter:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)-13)
```

to display **9/1/2014**